# MacBook Pro doesn't automatically go into Hibernate/Safe Sleep on empty battery (M1/Big Sur)

Tags: battery, sleep-wake, big-sur, hibernate, apple-silicon

Long gone are the times when my MacBook Pro 2012 automatically went into hibernate when the battery was low. I always blamed it on my old battery. I recently bought a MacBook Pro M1 though, and was pretty certain this problem was no longer an issue.

I was wrong. The problem still persists. I have a fresh install and double-checked that I am on default settings.

`pmset -g`:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 powernap             1
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by powerd, coreaudiod)
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 disksleep            10
 standby              1
 displaysleep         2
```

Comparing it to my old MacBook I can see that a lot of settings are missing.

Although the setting `hibernatemode` doesn't show within `pmset -g`, I can see that it still exists and that the default is still `3`, because whenever I change it to a different value, the otherwise disabled button `Restore Defaults` in System Preferences gets enabled (Thus I obviously changed the defaults).

So: What the heck is going on?! Has this feature been removed?

Comment: Actually it started working again a few month ago (now that I'm on Ventura?)